Why does my headset keep coming loose?
Around 5 months ago I replaced the headset bearings in my Nukeproof Reactor. Ever since then, the headset will not stay tight. I tighten it up as normal using the following procedure:

Slacken the 2 stem bolts
Carefully tighten up the adjusting cap until the correct preload tension on the bearings is found. To do this, I apply the front brake using my right hand, then rock the headset back and forth using my left hand until I can feel that there is just zero play
Retighten the 2 stem bolts to 6Nm torque

As soon as I hit any kind of jump, or rough terrain, the play comes back.
I've tried:

reassembling the headset from scratch
cleaning the steerer tube with isopropyl alcohol to ensure there's no grease there which could cause a loose bond between the steerer tube and the stem

The headset spec is: 44-56 IITS, ZS44-28.6T2/ZS56/40 B8. The replacement bearings were from "Blueseal" in a kit (like this).
Any ideas? Are these bearings just rubbish?
Update: I bought some official Nukeproof headset bearings (off eBay since Nukeproof is no longer) and compared them with the Blueseal ones I had fitted. I found that the chamfer profile of the Nukeproof lower bearing is different. Not much, they're both 45 degrees but the 45 degree section is shorter on the Nukeproof one. I'm fairly sure that this difference meant that the old Blueseal bearing didn't have an even, tight fit with the lower compression ring. Need to test ride it to make sure.

Do you really what to know why it comes loose or are you searching for a fix?

Is there any way to mark the exact position of the stem on the steer tube?  Maybe the stem isn't moving on the steer tube but the new headset bearings aren't fully seated?  And then when you hit something, one of the bearings seats itself a bit deeper?

@AndrewHenle That's a good idea. I can remove the top cap and use calipers to measure the distance the steerer tube protrudes from the stem. If it doesn't change I know it's the bearings moving.

@BenediktBauer both :) Once I have the why I'm guessing the fix will be simple.

Do you put anything on the stem bolts (grease, loctite)?   Thread in good condtion?

@mattnz no, nothing. Threads are in reasonable condition.

I had that symptom on a bike I had taken to service into a bike shop. When I checked for myself, one of the bearings has been installed upside down. The bearing cage had a shape that somewhat led to that mistake.

It's unlikely to be the quality of the bearings per se. Them being less smooth and wearing out faster, perhaps, but even a crappy bearing won't be straight up loose if fully preloaded. A few considerations:

Are the bearing seats clean and smooth?
You have a semi-integrated headset. It's generally recommended to preload any type of integrated headset harder than you would a non-integrated headset. The extra clamping force helps keep the bearings pressed firmly against their seats.
On that note, wobbling the headset with the stem loose may not be fully indicative of the level of preload. I prefer to judge the smoothness of rotation instead--tighten until you detect any sign of roughness and then back off a little.
How much of a gap is there between the top of the steerer and the bottom of the top cap? It's possible that you were always marginal on this gap, the new bearings are ever so slightly thinner, and now you're bottoming out before achieving proper preload.
Try to rotate your bars with the stem tightened. Is your stem loose; i.e. are you able to move it around?
Are you sure it's not movement in your fork (steerer tube loose is loose in the crown, lower leg bushings are shot, etc.)?
This is unlikely to be a problem, but check that the angles of your bearings are as intended. You might get play if you try to use a 36×45° bearing on a 45×45° crown race or something.


The bearing chamfers were not the same as the originals which was causing the issue.

Steps I would take. Overtighten the cap bolt and then back it off to correct preload. The feel as you do this will probably indicate if the bearings are not seated properly. I am not suggesting 'gorilla with spanner' level of overtighten, just enough.
Put some carbon paste on the steerer, grease the threads of the stem bolts and tighten. If stem bolts are aluminum replace them with stainless (Not sure who would use aluminum in such a mission critical....)

+1. I would overtighten the preload adjustment a bit (just to the point where you need a tiny bit force to turn the handlebars), then shake the bike, smash the front wheel on the ground a bit and so on to make sure the bearing is really seated. Then back off the preload.

Do tighten the bolts alternatively(instead of one full on and then the other). If it is possible that the bolts themselves have ever been over-tightened do replace them too(out of desperation).
Now that the bike is perfectly setup, look at the clearance between the 2 plates the bolts are "trying to bring together". I've forgotten the root cause but on one bike those plates would lay flush against each other when properly tightened. Not safe to ride.

He's using a torque wrench to 6Nm yo.

@Noise When you tighten a nut, static friction makes it look "more tightened" - to the wrench. Thus "cross-tightening" of screws has been standard practice since we learned how to cut a thread. I think it was a British guy designing cannons.

Your scenario is mostly hypothetical. A single bolt is generally sufficient to hold the stem, though certainly not advisable. The type of problem the Questor seeks information on would leave noticeable witness marks on the steerer if it was slipping as you suppose. Your scenario might give some noticeable problem over an extended timeframe, at worst. Does that seem reasonable?

Not at all! In my case everything points to mismatched diameters - not as noticeable as "1 and 1/8" in a "1 and 1/4" race to wobble but still be incompatible. It was _not_ safe to ride due to the reasons outlined by OP.

If your answer turns out to be correct, I will happily display your gold-framed portrait in my shop. My feeling is that you have made a relevant and succinct answer to a different question.

@Noise I really hope You display no portrait because those errors tend to show up in the least convenient moment. The entire purpose of my answer is for OP to skim over and say to himself "nah, not it" and forget forever.
